# OCaml: List of lists

Tags: ocaml

I need to iterate through a list of lists in ocaml. How can i iterate through a list of lists comparing each element of each list to zero? If an element is greater than zero it returns false and stops the recursion.

the function ***must*** have the signature: int list list -> bool

Please do not show me ways using "array." or the keyword "in". Any help would be great!

Comment: You should show us what you have done so far.  This is not the place to get your homework answer for free.

Comment: Use List.fold and List.forall

Comment: *"Please do not show me ways using "array." or the keyword "in". Any help would be great!"* : Ok. Please __do__ show us what you've done so far. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
let all_lte_zero xss = List.for_all (fun xs -> List.for_all (fun x -> x <= 0) xs) xss;;
```

According to the ocaml documentation, `for_all p [a1; ...; an]` checks if all elements of the list satisfy the predicate p.

So if any element is greater than 0, the predicate `fun x -> x <= 0` will evaluate to false and so both `List.for_all`s will evaluate to false.